# Custom view does not draw correctly

Tags: java, android

I am just trying to create a horizontal line. I have painted the view red and then added a blue line which I thought should take half the height.

Since I say that my custom view is 40 dp in height I would have thought that the blue bar with 20 dp in height would fill it half ways. But it doesn't. It takes 1/4 instead of 1/2. How can I fix that?

```
public class MyProgressView extends View {

    public MyProgressView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MyProgressView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(dipToPx(20));
        canvas.drawLine(0, 0, 300, 0, paint);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        int parentWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);

        setMeasuredDimension(parentWidth, dipToPx(40));
    }

    private int dipToPx(int dp) {
        return (int) getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density * dp;
    }
}
```

and XML:

```
<view
        class="com.company.MyProgressView"
        android:background="#ff0000"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        />
```

Comment: It's been a while since I've drawn lines, but I believe it could be because the bottom half of the line is getting clipped.  Try to raise it by 10 dp and see if you get more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case `drawLine` method draws a line on Y=0. This means your line's center position on Y is 0. If you set stroke  width to 20, it is going to fill -10 and +10.

There are 2 different solutions:

1. You can set stroke with to 40(which will fill -20 and +20)

   You can set your Y to 10 on your drawLine method(which will fill 0 and +20).